# extracting individual images from a sprite

Tags: sprite

I have a sprite, containing 7 x 2 images. 
What I would like is a way to extract those 14 images, and be able to access those individual images with a name (eg img01.png, img02.png, etc)

I'm afraid the "classical" css sprites extractor, making only

elements, would not fit my needs, I'm looking for images that I can handle as images.

Thanks for your help (css, java script... whatever !)

Comment: Please add what you have tried. Also, if your end goal is to simply have 14 image files; why not just use 14 image files?

Comment: It's for a website, and a sprite increase the response time of the site and Google seems to penalize slow sites. I want to have pictures used for a menu, with hover effects. But the css / html examples I found on the Internet only work with lists (<li>), and I can't have the pictures centered in the page. On the opposite, I know how to center pictures, that's the reason I want to deal with pictures.